# Highcharts - Export as image - X-axis labels not showing icons

Tags: highcharts

We're trying to **export** the Highchart API based chart as an image. 
Though, the chart is converted correctly to image, but in-case we have **custom icons** in-place of x-axis labels, then its not displayed. Whereas in-case of text, it displays correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried?

Comment: Defaulty HTML elements (like <img>) are not exported. You need to use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image) in [load](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) event.

Comment: @Irshad: I can surely share my code, but its actually meant for a IPAD application with offline images/icons. Can you let us know how we can share our zip file (JS/html/images) ?

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks for the info, I'll give it a try if that works for me.